# Extracting the complete decimal part of the number in R

Tags: r

How can I extract the decimal part of the number? Say I have a decimal number, **my_num <- 3.55**.

Comment: The answer because the subject was closed in similar but not really the same.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are multiple ways to solve and extract the decimal part some are:
lets store the result in *dec*

1. `dec <- my_num - floor(my_num)`
2. `dec <- my_num%%1`
3. `dec <- my_num - as.integer(my_num)`
4. `dec <- my_num - trunc(my_num)`

all these will result the same.

Comment: "all these will result the same" is not true. The first two examples only work for positive numbers. The last two also work for negative numbers.